# Change color of GridView Cell depending on Time

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

[image]

I have a gridview above that displays reason and time.

What I want to do is:

- To display the color RED when time is `BETWEEN 12:00:00 PM and 12:59:59 PM AND is Beginning of Day`
- To display the color GREEN when time is `BETWEEN 13:00:00 PM and 13:59:59 PM AND is LUNCH`

I have it working for the column REASON.

Below is my code. Note: e.Row.Cells[4] is for Column Reason, e.Row.Cells[5] is for Column Time

```
protected void GridViewEmployee_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Works
        if (e.Row.Cells[4].Text == "Break")
        {
            e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

        //Doesn't Work
        //if (e.Row.Cells[4].Text == "Beginning Of Day" && e.Row.Cells[5].Text > " 12:00:00 PM " && e.Row.Cells[5].Text < "12:59:59 PM")
        //{
        //    e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = Color.Red;
        //}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing time value with string. So try something like this and make sure when you are using `<` or `>` operator then both value must be datetime type.

```
DateTime.Parse(e.Row.Cells[5].Text) > DateTime.Parse("12:00:00 PM ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
    if(DateTime.Now > 12:00:00 && DateTime.Now < 13:00:00)
    {
      dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
```